# iOS - Generate map image for the latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit

I have searched the internet but couldn't find if I can get the map image from the latitude and logitude.

Is there any api which can give me the map image .
Because I got start location and end location.

When I give the start and end location , it should give me map image with route . 
Is the possible .

**If I am on mapview I can manage snapshot , but here I won't have any mapview.**

Any links, ideas , suggestions highly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if there are any API´s available for this, but when I do this I just call the Apple Maps app and provide a `latitude` and `longitude` for my position and open up that app.

In that way the user can use the Apple Maps application to navigate and get full information about roads etc.

Here is how I call this:

```
func navigateWithAppleMaps(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "Start"
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
}
```

Comment: I want map images to display in my map history tableview cells.
because I can't initialize maps to each tableview cells

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use google developer static map api for this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Comment: that's good link I am reading this thanks 
but not getting sample codes , I am searching btw

Comment: you have to use sample url which is given in site and use your api key

Answer (score 1):

You can get image from just passing latitude and longitude from following code. You can set zoom on mapview in URL.

```
var staticMapUrl: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|\(YOUR LATITUDE HERE),\(YOUR LONGITUDE HERE)&\("zoom=16&size=400x400")&sensor=true"
var mapUrl = URL(string: staticMapUrl.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
var image = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: mapUrl))
```

Comment: thanks at least I can get the image from my latitude and longitude.  But I need to get the route between two locations. Can you help more ? :) :)

Comment: you can't get this type of image. for this you have to use google map api

Comment: with google map api you can easily track the direction between two locations

Comment: @user3804063 at least you can accept my answer for your question it will help others

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 5 creating two pins on map and path between them

Lets first get path between 2 points using google api:

```
//=== get points ===
var encodedPathPoints = "" //we'll get this from google api
let pointsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(location1.lat!),\(location1.long!)&destination=\(location2.lat!),\(location2.long!)&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=\(ServiceConstants.MAP_KEY)"

if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
    AF.request(pointsUrl).responseJSON { response in
        let json = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
        if json != nil {
            print("JSON map results: \(json)")
            let routes = json!["routes"].arrayValue

            for route in routes
            {
                let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                if points != nil {
                    encodedPathPoints = points!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once i have path between my two points let set static map image

```
let MAP_BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
let MAP_IMAGE_SIZE = "size=\(2 * Int(imageView.frame.size.width))x\(2 * Int(imageView.frame.size.height))"
let MAP_MARKER = "&markers=icon:https://www.google.com|";//your icon url
let MAP_deliveryLocation = "\(location.lat!),\(location.long!)"
let MAP_WAYPOINT = "\(storeLocation.lat!),\(storeLocation.long!)"
let MAP_KEY = "&key=\(ServiceConstants.MAP_KEY)"
let MAP_STYLE = "&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry|color:0xf5f5f5&style=element:labels.icon|visibility:off&style=element:labels.text.fill|color:0x616161&style=element:labels.text.stroke|color:0xf5f5f5&style=feature:administrative.land_parcel|element:labels.text.fill|color:0xbdbdbd&style=feature:poi|element:geometry|color:0xeeeeee&style=feature:poi|element:labels.text.fill|color:0x757575&style=feature:poi.park|element:geometry|color:0xe5e5e5&style=feature:poi.park|element:labels.text.fill|color:0x9e9e9e&style=feature:road|element:geometry|color:0xffffff&style=feature:road.arterial|element:labels.text.fill|color:0x757575&style=feature:road.highway|element:geometry|color:0xdadada&style=feature:road.highway|element:labels.text.fill|color:0x616161&style=feature:road.local|element:labels.text.fill|color:0x9e9e9e&style=feature:transit.line|element:geometry|color:0xe5e5e5&style=feature:transit.station|element:geometry|color:0xeeeeee&style=feature:water|element:geometry|color:0xc9c9c9&style=feature:water|element:labels.text.fill|color:0x9e9e9e&size=480x360"
let PATH = "&path=color:0x11C856|weight:5|enc:\(encodedPathPoints)" //use 'enc:' if you're using encoded path just like me, you can ignore this if you're using normal lat lng points concatenated in string.
let mapStaticImgUrlStr = "\(MAP_BASE_URL)\(MAP_IMAGE_SIZE)\(PATH)&center=\(MAP_deliveryLocation)|\(MAP_WAYPOINT)\(MAP_MARKER)\(MAP_deliveryLocation)\(MAP_MARKER)\(MAP_WAYPOINT)\(MAP_STYLE)\(MAP_KEY)"

let url = URL(string: mapStaticImgUrlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)

do {
    let data = try NSData(contentsOf: url3!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
} catch {
    imageView.image = UIImage()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in My Case :
Get image between two locations markers Google maps

```
let api_Key = "put your api key from google maps"
    //Add your coordinate origin and destination 
let staticMapUrl: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green%7Clabel:P%7C24.226334030227406,55.7664223574102&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C25.20909416014038,55.29933510348201&key=\(api_Key)&size=1000x1000&zoom=7&sensor=true"
    
let mapUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: staticMapUrl)!
//Print The url
print("url\(mapUrl)")
//Load image on UI
self.mapViewImage.downloadImage(imageUrl: staticMapUrl, type: .imageMap)
```